# How to prepopulate _form for featured objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, object, attributes

A user can input a custom `:action` or choose a featured `:action`:

```
<%= f.text_field :action %>
  Or choose a featured challenge:
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :action, [['Run a Mile','Run a Mile'], ['Drink 16oz of Water','Drink 16oz of Water'], ['Take a Picture','Take a Picture'], ['1 Drink Max','1 Drink Max'], ['See Eiffel Tower','See Eiffel Tower'], ['Write a Book','Write a Book'], ['Skydive','Skydive'], ['Start a Business','Start a Business'], ['No Snooze','No Snooze'], ['Visit All 50 States','Visit All 50 States'], ['Talk to a Stranger','Talk to a Stranger'], ['Try a New Recipe','Try a New Recipe'], ['Media-fast','Media-fast']], :first, :last %>
```

If a user chooses a featured `:action` the new challenges/_form is pre-populated with his chosen `:action`, but now I'd like to take it to the next level with your help!

```
<%= form_for(@challenge)  do |f| %>
  Challenge: <%= f.text_field :action %>
  Do On: <%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed %>
  Do For: <%= f.number_field :days_challenged %>
<% end %>
```

How can I pre-populate the other attributes of a featured challenge like, "Do For" or "Do On"?

For example if a user chose the featured `:action`: `'Run a Mile` then I would pre-populate the form with `Run a Mile`, `Mon, Wed, Fri`, `30 Days`.

Comment: You can initialize the `Challenge` instance with values, like `@challenge = Challenge.new(days_challenged: 12)`, and then in your form you will see `12` as a pre-filled value for `days_challenged`

Comment: Hi @MrYoshiji, but let's say I have like 100 featured challenges. How could I have a separate pre-filled value for each one?

Comment: Is doing it in javascript an option?

Comment: Yea I'm open to whatever works @Shishir. I'm just not good at javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `simple_form` with `reform`. Reform will give you form object, where you can override methods that will populate your form.

Here is a watered-down example (you will have to adjust it to your case):

```
class ChallengeForm < Reform::Form
  property :action
  property :committed
  property :days_challenged

  model :challenge

  def commited
    super || action_to_commited_hash[model.action]
  end

  def days_challenged
    super || action_to_days_challenged_hash[model.action]
  end

  def action_to_days_challenged_hash
    {
      'Run a Mile' => 30,
      'Take a Picture' => 12
    }
  end

  def action_to_commited_hash
    {
      'Run a Mile' => ['Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri'],
      'Take a Picture' => ['Tu', 'Thu']
    }
  end
end
```

`super` in the methods above will delegate to the `model`. Note that you are overriding `getter` methods, and it doesn't affect `setters` (you can override setters too if you wanted to change form data before writing it).

In your template, instead of

```
form_for @challenge
```

you will have:

```
simple_form_for @form
```

It's a super common form library for Rails and I can't imagine not using it myself!

Comment: Hey okay so I made a folder app/forms then I created `challenge_form.rb` with your code in it. I switched my other form to `simple_form_for @form`. Is this right so far? I can't get it to work from there, neither `action_to_days_challenged_hash` or `action_to_commited_hash` is being set in the secondary form. Only the `action` still sets

Comment: HTML Output: `Do For: <input class="day-challenge" type="number" name="challenge[days_challenged]" id="challenge_days_challenged" />` I don't if that's helpful.

Comment: Seems right. Are you passing the model to the form as described in reform readme? https://github.com/apotonick/reform (Sorry, I should have specified that I'm really talking about `simple_form` + `reform` usage) - updated my answer.

Comment: No problem. Still a little confused by it. Sorry. So I added the gem `reform-rails` & the gem `reform`. I then created initializers/reform.rb and added `require "reform/form/dry" Reform::Form.class_eval do feature Reform::Form::Dry end`. But I keep getting the error `uninitialized constant Reform::Form (NameError) ` even though I ran `bundle install` Also do I add anything else to challenges_controller or challenge.rb?

Comment: Hm, that's weird. And you are definitely not running spring? In the controller you would initialize the form and pass it to the template `@form = ChallengeForm.new(@challenge)`

Comment: Yea not using spring. Do you know how I could initialize in the controller? Maybe that's the trick like create some sort of method in there? Here was my attempt: `before_action :populate_challenge, only: [:create]` and then in the create action:   `def populate_challenge(challenge)
    require "reform/form/dry" 
    Reform::Form.class_eval do 
      feature Reform::Form::Dry 
    end
  end` I updated the question so you can see what my controller looks like. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Not sure I'm following your controller logic - is `create` a GET action? Calling `@form.validate(params)` will update form fields with data and `@form.save` will save the challenge model. There are some good docs here: https://github.com/apotonick/reform#the-api

Comment: I think the best place for the contents of `populate_challenge` is in initializers. I'm using `reform` version `1.2.6`, so I don't need the `reform-rails` gem. I have just the following statement in my `initializers/reform.rb`: `Reform::Form.reform_2_0!`. However I think this line is not necessary in latest version of `reform`, as per here: https://github.com/apotonick/reform/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Comment: Yea that got rid of the initializers problem :] Now I've been struggling with setup. I guess because I might be doing it a little wacky with the GET action in `def create`. I'm sure your answer will help people with this general problem, but I decided to create another question that more specifically addresses my problem if you want to continue the conversation over there with me :] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667978/how-to-use-reform-to-prepopulate-for-featured-objects